# Problema botón Modal Bootstrap

Tags: botón, bootstrap

estoy empezando a programar nuevamente, tenía muchos años que no lo hacía y me he topado con este fallo que me da un botón modal boostrap de un ejemplo sacado de la página getboostap.com

Yo lo pego en mi archivo index.php que es mi plantilla web que tiene las referencias y llamadas los ccs, los plugins, los js etc..etc ya que es una plantila responsive que descargue también para pruebas pero sencillamente el botón no hace nada y debería mostrar como si fuera un alert los ... puntos que aparecen en el div de la clase modal-body, lo he probado en chrome, ie y nada el botón está muerto. alguien que pueda ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como estas llamando al css y los js?

Porque me funciona de maravilla

Comment: Me baje el Adminlte y cree la carpeta en mi sitio, ya el AdminLTE trae un index que tiene todas las llamadas a archivos js, ccs, enlaces etc, desde ese mismo index que trae por defecto lo único que hice fue cambiar la ruta de esos archivos a mi carpeta local.

Comment: Ejemplo: <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> (Esta era la llamada por defecto)

Comment: <!-- jQuery -->

<script src="./dashboard/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script> (Esta es mi ruta)

Comment: Podrias subir una imagen de la estructura de tu proyecto, creo que el problema es la rutas, o la consola de la web.

Comment: Yo dejé la carpeta original del AdminLte con su index original sin modificaciones, con las rutas por defecto de los css, los plugins y los js y aun así pego el codigo el codigo del boton y no funciona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compañero, revise tu código, fíjate en los cdn o archivos que importas a tu pagina, porque si funciona bien, deje puestos los cdn para que revises, saludos.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas ya que tuve el tiempo de sentarme con calma a verificar, en efecto era un error de sintaxis en las rutas de los archivos que se importan un slash mal puesto. Saludos